# JavaFX: Custom Component throws LoadException only in Runnable JAR

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to generate a executable jar file from a JavaFX project I'm working on which is **running ok** when executing through the Eclipse IDE.
But when executing from the generated jar file, a runtime error occurs when the `FXML` tries to load a custom component (class which `extends` the JFX component `BorderPane`).
What's wrong?

Here's the `FXML` file, where a custom class, `CardPane`, which extends `BorderPane` is used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.tsi.ui.CardPane?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import com.tsi.ui.CardPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: #454449;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" opacity="0.99" prefHeight="386.0" prefWidth="380.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
           <!-- 
              The below command (referenced in the stack trace as line 40, 
              which here is not precise, since I've deleted some useless 
              stuff for the post propose) is where the error occurs
            -->
            <CardPane fx:id="pane00" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane01" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane02" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane10" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane11" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane12" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane20" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane21" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <CardPane fx:id="pane22" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>

      </GridPane>
   </center>

<!-- I will show only the interesting point -->
...

</BorderPane>
```

The CardPane is being used just as a class that extends BorderPane with the layout positions already populated with some other nodes. In this code, we've some of them populating the content of the cells of a GridPane.

Here's a few lines to show how it's defined:

```
public class CardPane extends BorderPane {

    private Card card;
    private Label cardName;
    private Label cardValue;
    private ImageView valueIcon;
    private HBox hBox;
    private Node armaSprite;

    public CardPane() {
        hBox = new HBox();
        cardName = new Label();
        cardValue = new Label();
        valueIcon = new ImageView(new Image(Sprite.CAMINHO + File.separator + "CoracaoIcon.png", 27, 22, false, false));
    }
```

I honestly don't know if this approach (extending the `BorderPane` class, making my own component this way) is a good practice. If not, I will be glad if someone could let me know what should be avoided.
But above all, the main point is, everything works fine inside Eclipse, but not when the project is exported. Why?

Here's the exception printed on Windows console. Again, it occurs only when the jar is executed with `java.exe -jar '.\Dungeon Cards.jar'`. Never on the IDE.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/ramon/Desktop/Dungeon%20Cards.jar!/com/tsi/ui/fxml/game.fxml:40

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at com.tsi.app.Jogo.<init>(Jogo.java:40)
        at com.tsi.app.DungeonCards.iniciarJogo(DungeonCards.java:138)
        at com.tsi.ui.Instrucoes.esconder(Instrucoes.java:72)
        at com.tsi.ui.Instrucoes$2.handle(Instrucoes.java:52)
        at com.tsi.ui.Instrucoes$2.handle(Instrucoes.java:1)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$352(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:659)
        at com.tsi.ui.CardPane.<init>(CardPane.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1009)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
        ... 51 more
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide the rest of the StackTrace. The `LoadException` is **not** going to be the root cause of the error. Look for a line starting with "Cause by:"

Comment: Oh, thanks! I totally missed this line. I feel stupid about it :P I think I (or you) have just found the root cause. I've updated the post with the full trace. The problem is in the constructor,  while instancing the `ImageView` and I already solved it. I will also solve the question explaining why it was not working. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Zephyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6485651/zephyr) pointed how I've missed the "Caused By:" statement on the StackTrace when writing the post. It clearly indicates that the  `ImageView` could not be instantiated due a malformed URL.

The trick is that I had the following constant pointing to the root path of where my image resources are:

```
public static final String CAMINHO = "/com/tsi/sprites";
```

The URL was being defined as `CAMINHO + File.separator + [image_file].png`

Resulting in: `"/com/tsi/sprites\[image_file].png"`

The `File.separator` used on the constructor concatenation is holding the Windows pattern of file separating (**backslash**), while the constant value `CAMINHO` uses **normal slashes** (Linux pattern). 
Somehow, Eclipse can abstract that misplaced combination, but while running outside it, Windows doesn't.

To solve it, I just changed `File.separator` to `"/"`.

As it says in [this  article](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/how_to_use_file_separator_when), while working with resources, `File.separator` should be avoided:

"*[...] use system-specific file separator only when working with files and when displaying a path to the user. For all other cases use forward slash.*"